# Notation for newton-like expansion

Tags: combinatorics, notation, combinatorial-proofs, newton-raphson, newton-series

Is there a compact way of referring to the expression $$a^n + a^{n - 1}b + a^{n - 2}b^2 + \cdots + b^n\:?$$ Maybe some notation I do not know about it.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a finite geometric series (with ratio $r=b/a$), so use the geometric series formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @MikeEarnest notes, it's a finite geometric progression with $n+1$ terms, of sum $\frac{a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}}{a-b}$. With [classical $q$-analogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-analog#%22Classical%22_q-theory) it can be written as $a^n[n+1]_{b/a}$, or $b^n[n+1]_{a/b}$.

Comment: The nice feature of expression in question is that it is homogeneous in $\,a,b\,$ and symmetric. I propose $\,[n\!+\!1]_{a,b}\,$ whose special cases are $\,[n]_{q,1} = [n]_{1,q} = [n]_q.$

Comment: @Somos Maybe this can be a starting point for the invention of $q$-analogs with $d$-dimensional $q$.

Comment: Actually, I propose homogeneous versions of all of the classical polynomials such as Bernoulli, Chebyshev, Fibonacci, Hermite, Legendre, Laguerre, Lucas, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Using [sigma notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Capital-sigma_notation), you can write it as
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}a^{n-k}b^k \, .
$$

Comment: that's great but I was thinking something more like {n \choose k} or similar.

Comment: @BobVance The expression doesn't include binomial coefficients. Or do you mean you want a compact symbol as elegant as that? If so, see my answer.

Comment: @BobVance: I don't know of any specific notation to refer to this series, but you could say 'let $S=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a^{n-k}b^k$' and then whenever you want to refer to the series you can reference $S$.

Comment: @J.G. that's exactly what I was looking for: something as elegant as the compact symbol for "n choose k".